# How to split a list in two over a condition?

Tags: list, perl, partition, perl-module

Is there a [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep)-like function that splits a list into both the part that matches the expression, as `grep` does, and also its complement?

Of course it would be very simple to write such a function, but I'm interested to know if it already exists and would be more conveniently included from any of the `List::Util`-like modules.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer browsing through List::MoreUtils right after posting the question (my apologies). It's [part](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#part-BLOCK-LIST):

> Partitions LIST based on the return value of BLOCK which denotes into which partition the current value is put.
> Returns a list of the partitions thusly created. Each partition created is a reference to an array.

```
my $i = 0;
my @part = part { $i++ % 2 } "a".."h";   # Returns [qw( a c e g )], [qw( b d f h )]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're in an environment that won't let you install modules, here's a version of `List::MoreUtils::part` that doesn't depend on anything:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

sub part(&@) {
    my $f = shift;
    my @parts;
    for (@_) {
        my $bucket = $f->();
        push @{$parts[$bucket]}, $_;
    }
    return @parts;
}

my ($evens, $odds) = part { $_ % 2 } 1..10;
say "Even numbers: @$evens";
say " Odd numbers: @$odds";
```

Comment: @TLP The original also has a XS implementation that's faster and should be preferred unless you have grumpy sysadmins. (Note I wasn't trying to play code golf)